# Home page letters

Tags: plugins, functions

I want to make all of my Menu in Capital letters but yhe home page isn't working with that 
can somebody help me 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by css.Try with **.home** class.

**For example:

Theme Used:** [Basic](https://wordpress.org/themes/basic/)

**CSS code**

```
.home .top-menu li a, .top-menu li span { text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Hope this will helps you.